# Como criar tabelas de relacionamento 1:N?

Tags: sql, python, banco-de-dados, sqlite3, entidade-relacionamento

Eu já estudei banco de dados e compreendo como funciona a diagramação desse tipo de relação, mas agora que estou tentando implementar esse banco de dados com uso de sqlite3 e python eu vi alguns problemas. 
Eu tenho o seguinte banco de dados
[image: Diagrama de BD espectroradiômetros]

O problema é que eu tenho a necessidade de criar novas tabelas de Esp (U,IV,e Vis) para cada uma das linhas da tabela Mestre.
Cada linha da tabela Mestre tem dados correspondentes a um dia de leituras de três sensores. Esses sensores possuem uma leitura em dados de duas colunas com dados que correspondem a um gráfico (plano cartesiano x,y). Existiria três tabelas de pares x,y (mais de mil linhas) pra cada uma das linhas da tabela mestre
Posso ilustrar a relação da seguinte forma[image: Diagrama simplificado] Onde o realce vermelho vai corresponder aos dados que devem estar relacionados.

Então minha dificuldade está na criação das tabelas, porque eu não posso criar duas tabelas com o mesmo nome, e então eu teria que ficar criando as tabelas Esp com a nomenclatura Esp_U1,Esp_U2,Esp_U3...? Isso não parece certo de jeito nenhum

Por favor alguém me indique o que fazer a respeito da criação, vão ser tabelas com nomenclaturas muito diferentes. Qual seria a forma correta de se fazer a implementação do relacionamento 1:M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já foi resolvido o problema.
Sempre tive problema em entender o conceito, mas NA VERDADE, ao criar um relacionamento 1:N não estou criando muitas tabelas pra uma tabela, só estou criando mais linhas na tabela existente e numerando um campo para dizer de qual "instancia" da tabela o dado pertence. então eu não preciso criar mais tabelas, o conceito é simplesmente adicionar o valor na mesma tabela, mas referenciar como se fosse outra com uso de mais valores na chave estrangeira.

Qualqer coisa desculpem a confusão

Answer (score 0):

Cara se você precisar criar tabelas novas para seus dados quer dizer que sua arquitetura do SGBD como um todo está errada.

Tem que rever todos os dados e o que você está querendo fazer com a sua aplicação.

Explica-me melhor o que é o seu problema
por que dependendo você precisa de uma estrutura auxiliar uma tabela de junção.
pois em casos de M:M

O que é essa tabela mestre?

ela reúne os dados das outras tabela?

Se sim diagramou errado
talvez falte uma estrutura. ou talvez você não entendeu uma coisa mais simples a tabela que você criou administra todos os dados.

As tabelas são genericamente um meio de guardar informações

ou seja uma tabela frutas pode guardar todas as frutas e não somente as verdes.

Comment: eu vou tentar explicar melhor, mas acho que o diagrama pode estar errado mesmo. vou editar e inserir uma explicação melhor

Comment: cara diz o que voce queria explicar com o seu projeto eu posso lhe ajudar a montar o modelo ou lhe mostrar o que há de errado na forma que está pensando mas preciso de uma ajuda.

Comment: eu acho que entendi o meu erro, depois de observar melhor, num relacionamento 1:M eu na verdade não estaria criando várias tabelas não é?